# How does diffuse reflectance brightness varies with the line of sight?

Tags: visible-light, reflection

[Wikipedia asserts that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffuse_reflection)

> The rays represent luminous intensity, which varies according to Lambert's cosine law for an ideal diffuse reflector.

Describing this figure:

[image]

I understand this is a perceptual phenomenon, and we are observing the light coming from an object that is diffusely - and isotropically - reflecting light. and that the Lambert Cosine has to do with how stretching a circle on one axis increase its area.

However, I do not understand how or why this stretch happens, since (in my mental representation) we are always looking at small cylinders of light that come straight (normal) to the eye surface.

Can you explain, or maybe include a simple draw of how you image this?

Comment: II you think of " a small cylinders of light " normal to the ey, you neglect the comparatively large angle you see .

Comment: what do you mean? @trula

Comment: Usually it is called angle of vision, so for example you see your complete computer screen without moving your ey.